# Export locations marked in gogle mymaps with latitude and longitude in google mymaps

Tags: mymaps

I have a set of addresses imported to google mymaps. I want now to extract these locations with the coordinates in google mymaps.
I downloaded the KML file. But it doesn't show any coordinates

Excel file with latitude and longitude